# How to change routes with fixed ionic header after login?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have login page. After login i am routing to home page with side menu. How to navigate only content(route changing with different states) with fixed header for home page in ionic 1.x. Please help me.

Thanks,
Sandeep.

Comment: what router are you using? ui-router?

Comment: yes, I am using angular ui-router